# how can I force apt-get to replace installed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Sometimes I need to modify some configuration files in installed packages. 
For example I modified **/etc/pam.d/polkit-1** file and after I tried modified file I forgot its original version so I removed it hoping that reinstalling **policykit-1** package would replace it, so I did

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall policykit-1
```

but it did not replace it though `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1` belongs to `policykit-1`

I also I tried `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --reinstall policykit-1`  though `--force-overwrite` option used to override files installed by different packages.

Would anybody tell me how to do that with `apt-get`? I need to know it because I frequently modify files in my system. Though I can fix it manually.